# Can editing an image description trigger showing the Markdown diff in suggested edits, as is done with link changes?

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, images

I query posts on several sites for missing image descriptions needed for screen reader software.

Occasionally, a reviewer rejects it (*when using Inline or Side-by-side modes*) because they seemingly ignore my edit summary believing that the edit makes no visible change to the post and thus has no improvement whatsoever, or because they see the image highlighted in red and think I suggested deleting it.

- https://diy.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/133327
- https://diy.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/133337

Only in *Side-by-side Markdown* is the change to the image description visible. Can this be changed? I know it would affect all sites so I know it isn't quickly patched. I am patient, however...

... I am losing patience with reviewers who have rejected the same suggestion multiple times because they apparently aren't reading the edit summary or bothering to review in a different mode.

Currently, there is a feature whereby the system will trigger showing the Markdown view in a suggested edit, if there's a link changed in a post's rendered output. This request is asking that this be extended to image description changes as well. This will also help fight against suggested edit spam where someone tries to edit a spam link into an image description (while making other edits).

Comment: Both of them were rejected by the answer author, ultimately it is their decision what is done to the post. (although it is clear they just aren't paying attention)

Comment: Also, as an aside, they're vise-grips, not vice grips as described in your image description

Comment: Meh, I'd just leave a comment on their post instead and explain the situation, that way they can't miss it. It's not worth the effort submitting the edit multiple times if OP isn't paying attention (Which you have done, although poorly toned. Chill, people miss things, the edit summary is normally full of garbage and likely most people just pass by it, no need to get antsy).

Comment: @Sonic, your edit seems to go pretty far, from "this is a problem, please fix somehow" to "do this specific thing to fix the problem". Maybe it's better as an answer?

Comment: Seemed like Sonic added issues related to the review process to me. Only the new title question was a little confusing.

Comment: @bobble The question was there before Sonic's change: *"Only in Side-by-side Markdown is the change to the image description visible. Can this be changed soon?"*, the edit just adds more info - your comment makes it seem like you're only looking at the question title

Comment: @Nick: Can you provide a reference? There is (was?) a tradename, *"Vise-Grips"*. Has it become a common noun (*"vise-grips"* or *"vise-grip"*)? From *[Locking pliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locking_pliers)*: *""Mole" and "Vise-Grip" are trade names of different brands of locking pliers, yet mechanics and do-it-yourself hobbyists and craftspeople generically refer to locking pliers as "Vise-Grips" in the US, and "Mole grips" in the UK. In Ireland the tool is known as a "vice grip"."*

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q it's stamped right into the metal work in the photo

Comment: I rotated the image so it is easier to read, but the software still only reads the words the same with or without a hyphen.

Comment: @Nick, that doesn't mean what I think you think it means - it's asking for the difference to be made more obvious *somehow*, without any reference to auto-setting the mode. But it's not worth arguing, I guess, since OP seems fine with the change

Comment: @bobble Ah yes, I could just as easily argue that it doesn't mean what I think you think it means ;)

Comment: It took me a minute to understand Sonic's addition. It certainly went into further detail then I thought necessary, and elaborated on an issue (spam) I wasn't even aware of, but see how that is possible. So I left it. My failings were pointed out, and I can only try to work with that solution. But it's not an answer I will accept just yet.

Answer (score 10):

> "... they seemingly ignore my edit summary ...".

And why shouldn't they ignore it as all they get fed is: *image desc* and on the next one, slightly better: *image description only (i am not removing the image)*.

Let's first try a tad more verbosity in the edit summary on your end so reviewers could at least understand from the summary what they should be looking at before we put SE devs at work to switch the preferred review view for a reviewer at the digression of the user making an edit.

I have the patience to wait for editors to become as accurate as they expect the reviewers to be.

I can't imagine this happens often in the grand-scheme of things. Let's not spend time on this.

Comment: Exactly this. I changed the [edit summary for one of my scripts](https://diy.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/102025) after I noticed people were rejecting edits because they didn't understand them.

Comment: Agreed. Can you add a proposal for what the edit summary ought to have been?

Comment: Understood. I should have automated my edit summaries 100 posts back. Can we agree that *Image description changed from **'enter image description here'** to something that describes the picture for screen reader software that the blind and visually-impaired use"*?

Comment: @GWarner that is at least a lot more telling so if reviewers and post owners then still reject en masse your helpful edits then we can revisit your FR.

Comment: @rene Thank you, I revised my last edit to put in a verbose summary. But I also rotated the vice-grips too (it took up too much screen space IMHO)

Comment: @GWarner I'd consider a summary like "image description changed to better match the post text". I would also add the tooltip in the same edit, for the case if image fails to load `https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwDBk.png "vice grips"`

Comment: @gnat That's right, I completely forget you can put image titles in Markdown that way... is that syntax documented in the SE Markdown help page(s)?

Comment: @zcoop98 yes, there is an example right when you editing, if you click question mark and pick "Images" in help toolbar: `https://i.imgur.com/I5DFV.jpg "tooltip"`, as well as an example in [editing help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images)